# Why should I decrease the text_label shape?

Tags: python, deep-learning, confusion-matrix, mobilenet

I have taken 160 images of data for testing and after training my image dataset and after print test_label shape and predictions shape,

```
print("Test Label shape: ",test_labels.shape)
print("Predictions shape: ",predictions.shape)

Test Label shape:  (160,)
Predictions shape:  (10, 2)
```

From the prediction shape and test label shape I should decrease the test_label shape otherwise it would show the error so I have used the below code for getting the confusion matrix,

```
cm = confusion_matrix(test_labels[:-150], predictions.argmax(axis=1))
```

And after using the below code it print the matrix,

```
import itertools
cm_plot_labels = ['disease_leaf','fresh_leaf']
plot_confusion_matrix(cm, cm_plot_labels, title='Confusion Mtrix')
```

**Below the matrix,**
[[10, 0]
[ 0, 0]]

**Note:**  Now I am confused about the matrix and have some questions, please share the opinion who knows why need to decrease test_label shape?

Is it possible to print the confusion matrix without decreasing the test_label shape. Because for decreasing the shape the confusion matrix provide the confusion matrix among 10 but I think it should provide the confusion matrix among 160.